# How to make a condition for event 'click' inside/outside for multiple divs?

Tags: javascript

I have a `html` And `js` as below :

```js
document.addEventListener('click', myFunction())

function myFunction(e) {
  let inputs = document.querySelectorAll('.my-element');
  let m = inputs.forEach((el) => el.contains(e.target));
  if (!m) {
    console.log('Element');
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="my-element" style: "width:100px; height: 100px">
</div>
<div class="my-element" style: "width:100px; height: 100px">
</div>
<div class="my-element" style: "width:100px; height: 100px">
</div>
```

The problem is, the condition works even if I click inside the target. I need that the condition works only if I click outside of the elements. What my mistake is?

Comment: Can you explain this in detail, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a click event to fire only if it isn't over certain elements you have to check if the event target is not the same as any it those elements

You almost have it except you are setting the value of m to a forEach which always returns undefined, then checking !m which will always be true

Just make a new array from the node list and set m to the .find value instead, so altogether

```
document.addEventListener('click', myFunction)

function myFunction(e) {
  let inputs = document.querySelectorAll('.my-element');
  let titles = document.querySelectorAll('.my-title');
  let m = Array.apply(0,inputs).find((el) => el.contains(e.target));
  if (!m) {
    console.log('Element');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here:

Because `inputs` is an nodelist you need to convert it to an array.

I have done i here with the spread operator `...`

You can also do it with `Array.from`, `[].concat(inputs)`

Then you filter the array for your `e.target` and check if the length is 0.

```js
document.addEventListener('click', myFunction)

function myFunction(e) {
  let inputs = document.querySelectorAll('.my-element');
  let m = [...inputs].filter(el => el === e.target);
  if (!m.length) {
    console.log('Element');
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="my-element" style="background: black;margin: 10px;width:100px; height: 100px">
</div>
<div class="my-element" style="background: black;margin: 10px;width:100px; height: 100px">
</div>
<div class="my-element" style="background: black;margin: 10px;width:100px; height: 100px">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `()` from `myFunction` in `document.addEventListener('click', myFunction())` just use `document.addEventListener('click', myFunction)`.

You can use [`Element.matches()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/matches) with `target` as `e.target.matches('.my-element')` and verify that it is the one you want. `matches` will take `selector` as `parameter`.

Try in below sample, when you click on `label` or `input` it won't `log` anything. When you click other part of `div` then it will `log`.

```js
document.addEventListener('click', myFunction);

function myFunction(e) {
  //let inputs = document.querySelectorAll('.my-element');
  //let titles = document.querySelectorAll('.my-title');
  //let m = inputs.forEach((el) => el.contains(e.target));
  if (e.target.matches('.my-element')) {
    console.log('Element', e.target.innerText);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="my-element" style: "width:100px; height: 100px">
  <label>abcd</label>
</div>
<div class="my-element" style: "width:100px; height: 100px">
<input type='text' value='input' />
</div>
<div class="my-element" style: "width:100px; height: 100px">c
</div>
```